# "Flood fill" child DIV elements inside a parent DIV with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flood-fill

I have a container DIV which has absolute positioned child DIVs inside it. The child DIVs can be dragged and dropped around in relation to the parent container DIV. (Using jQuery UI)

I need to add a functionality where if the user has a "fill" tool selected, then if he clicks inside a closed DIV area, he can fill the empty area with said child DIVs.

Imagine something like this http://jsfiddle.net/mCuLE/2/

css
    .block {
        position: absolute;
        width: 31px;
        height: 31px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background: yellow;
    }

```
.child-red {
    position: absolute;
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: red;
}

.child-blue {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: blue;
}

.child-green {
    position: absolute;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: green;   
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block" style="left: 0; top: 0;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 32px; top: 0;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 64px; top: 0;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 96px; top: 0;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 128px; top: 0;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 0; top: 32px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 0; top: 64px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 0; top: 96px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 0; top: 128px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 32px; top: 128px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 64px; top: 128px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 96px; top: 128px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 128px; top: 128px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 128px; top: 32px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 128px; top: 64px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 128px; top: 96px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="left: 64px; top: 64px;"></div>
</div>
```

Now if I click somewhere in the area inside the white empty space, it should fill with empty red DIVs.

Also note that the method should be flexible enough to accommodate child DIVs of different dimensions. 
I suppose it should be alright if the child DIV doesn't fit and "bleeds" out of the area.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want anything fancy, you could always just set the background colour of an element behind your grid of squares.

```
$(".backdrop").on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).css({ 'background-color': "red" });
});
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mCuLE/9/) of that solution.

Before I realized that this might be all you need, though, I came up with a slightly more general solution. The idea is that you have a grid of squares in your javascript, that exposes methods to add css classes based on conditions. This way you can write, for example,

```
// when I click an empty square, colour it and the adjacent empty squares red
grid.on("click", ".empty", function (clicked_square) {        
    // colour adjacent squares
    this.addClass("child-red", function (square) {            

        return grid.hasClass(square, "empty") && clicked_square.isAdjacent(square);
    });            

    // colour the square
    this.addClass("child-red", { x: clicked_square.x, y: clicked_square.y });        
});
```

This solution makes use of two classes, Grid and Square. It is only a partial solution, as I totally ran out of steam before writing an algorithm to walk all adjacent empty squares. Someone could probably whip that up in a second, but at the moment it's just beyond me. Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mCuLE/10/) you can play with.